# What's the difference between web.page.perf[host,<path>,<port>] and eb.test.time[Scenario,Step,resp] in Zabbix?

Tags: zabbix, latency

I want to monitor the **latency** of a web link in Zabbix. I found there are two ways to monitor the latency of a URL. Either creating an item with **web.page.perf**[URL] or creating a web scenario with Response time for step **web.test.time**[Scenario,Step,resp].
However, web.page.perf is usually longer than web.test.time.

Here is the Documentation about this two methods, but no idea which one I should use to monitor the latency.
[web.page.perf](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent#web.page.perfhostpathport)
[Scenario step items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/web_monitoring/items)

[The screenshot here is monitoring the same URL.
Left graph: web.page.perf
Right graph: web.test.time (response time for step of web scenario)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbvCC.png)

I have no idea which way/function I should use to monitor the latency or is more accurate for latency. Can anyone please help on this?